# Simple asp form

Tags: forms, asp-classic, contact-form

Trying to get a very simple classic asp form up and running on 123-reg.

123-reg provide a script to get this done but I have no idea how this script connects to the form I've made.

Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form id="form" target="_blank" action="script.asp" method="post">

Name: <input name="Name" type="text" /><br />
Customer ID: <input name="Customer ID" type="text" /><br />
Email Address: <input name="Email" type="text" /><br />
Comments:<br />
<textarea name="Comments" rows=5 cols=50></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input type="reset" value="Clear" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the simple script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Secure Mail (ASP)</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container" class="index" style="padding:10px">

<br />
<br />
<h2>Secure Mail (ASP)</h2>
<br />

<%
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'To get the script for work please set the following values:

'Set the credentials for your email account to send the email from
username="MYUSERNAME"     'Insert your email account username between the double quotes            
password="MYPASSWORD"     'Insert your email account password between the double quotes              

'Set the from and to email addresses
sendFrom = "admin@MYURL.co.uk"   'Insert the email address you wish to send from   
sendTo = "MYEMAIL"     'Insert the email address to send to in here

'DO NOT CHANGE ANY SCRIPT CODE BELOW THIS LINE.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'This script demonstrates how to send an email using asmtp

'Create a CDO.Configuration object
Set objCdoCfg = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

'Configure the settings needed to send an email
objCdoCfg.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") ="intmail.atlas.pipex.net"
objCdoCfg.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
objCdoCfg.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objCdoCfg.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 0
objCdoCfg.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = username
objCdoCfg.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = password
objCdoCfg.Fields.Update

'Create the email that we are going to send
Set objCdoMessage = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objCdoMessage.Configuration = objCdoCfg
objCdoMessage.From = sendFrom
objCdoMessage.To = sendTo
objCdoMessage.Subject = "This is a test email."

'Add the email body text
objCdoMessage.TextBody = "Email sent using ASMTP from a ASP script."


On Error Resume Next

'Send the email
objCdoMessage.Send

'Check if an exception was thrown       
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'Response.Write "<FONT color=""Red"">Error: " & Err.Description & " (" & Err.Number & ")</FONT><br/>"
Else
    Response.Write "<FONT color=""Green"">The email has been sent to " & sendTo & ".</FONT>"
End If

'Dispose of the objects after we have used them
Set objCdoMessage = Nothing
Set objCdoCfg = Nothing
Set FSO = nothing
Set TextStream = Nothing
%>


</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

I know the script works as it sends the email, however none of the information included in the HTML form seems to be included.

Don't usually work with forms so any advice would be gratefully received.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in the asp are you requesting the form data to include in your email.

For example, instead of this in your asp:

```
sendTo = "MYEMAIL"     'Insert the email address to send to in here
```

You should use the email from the form:

```
sendTo = Request.Form("Email")     'Insert the email address to send to in here
```

You may want to validate the email address first:

```
if isEmailValid(Request.Form("Email")) = true then
    '#### Send your email
else
    '#### Email was invalid, give the user an error
    response.write "Invalid email address"
end if

Function isEmailValid(email) 
    Set regEx = New RegExp 
    regEx.Pattern = "^\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w{2,}$" 
    isEmailValid = regEx.Test(trim(email)) 
End Function
```

To confirm, the request.form collection uses the name="" property of the HTML form.
i.e. to include the contents of your textarea:

```
'Add the email body text
objCdoMessage.TextBody = "The following comment was submitted via the feedback form:" & Request.Form("Comments")
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but when I added your code I got an error message (error message 500). To add to my annoyance all form generators fail as well.